# ¿Cómo limitar/actualizar APIs PHP de Google usando "extra" desde composer?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-reporting

Yo quiero usar **sólo algunos servicios de Google**. [En la documentación](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#cleaning-up-unused-services) ellos dicen que se pueden limpiar los servicios no usados con algo como esto:

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/apiclient": "^2.7"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-update-cmd": "Google\\Task\\Composer::cleanup"
    },
    "extra": {
        "google/apiclient-services": [
            "Drive",
            "Analytics",
            "Sheets",
            "Gmail"
        ]
    }
}
```

Ese es mi actual `composer.json` y en `extra` le estoy indicando que instale solamente los archivos para usar las APIs: `Drive, Analytics, Sheets, Gmail` cosa que hace sin ningún problema.

Ahora yo quiero usar la API [AnalyticsReporting](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php?hl=es), y para ello agrego dicho servicio en `extra`:

```
"extra": {
    "google/apiclient-services": [
        "Drive",
        "Analytics",
        "AnalyticsReporting",
        "Sheets",
        "Gmail"
    ]
}
```

Guardo mi archivo `composer.json` y desde la consola escribo:

```
composer update
```

Y me lanza esta excepción:

```
Script Google\Task\Composer::cleanup handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

                                                                                
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                                    
  Google service "AnalyticsReporting" does not exist or was removed previously
```

Me dice que `AnalyticsReporting` no existe. En la [carpeta `Service` del repositorio de Github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/tree/master/src/Google/Service) hay una sub-carpeta para `Analytics`, y hay una sub-carpeta para `AnalyticsReporting`, por lo que entiendo que **son servicios distintos** y que mi `extra` debería funcionar bien.

Tengo código que usa la API Analytics y funciona sin problema. Pero si intento código usando la API AnalyticsReporting me da error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting' not found`, porque no me está instalando la carpeta de ese servicio y como es evidente no encuentra la clase.

¿Alguien sabe por qué no me reconoce `AnalyticsReporting` en `extra`? ¿Cómo puedo hacer para instalarlo sin tener que instalar todos los servicios de Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución estaba explicada al final del apartado [*Cleaning up unused services*](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#cleaning-up-unused-services) de la documentación:

> **IMPORTANT**: If you add any services back in composer.json, you will
> need to remove the vendor/google/apiclient-services directory
> explicity for the change you made to have effect ...

---

> **IMPORTANTE**: si vuelve a agregar algún servicio en `composer.json`,
> deberá eliminar explícitamente el directorio
> `vendor/google/apiclient-services` para que el cambio que realizó
> tenga efecto ...

Efectivamente, he eliminado el directorio `vendor/google/apiclient-services`, luego he ejecutado `composer update` en la consola y se han descargado las carpetas de los servicios indicados en `extra` únicamente.